# How to animate the GSM marker when its tapped - iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview, ios-animations

I'm working with a GMSMapView in my iOS app to display multiple location markers. When a user taps on a marker, I'd like to apply a bouncing animation to it. Is there a way to achieve this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I tried adding animation to the markers layer, but the app is crashing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.